# jQuery how to scale image with markers

Tags: jquery, scale, image-resizing

I have this:

```
<style>
#pic_wrapper{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
#selected_picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.pin {
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="pic_wrapper">
    <div id="selected_picture">
        <img src="map.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and append markers to the image with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
$(function(){
    $('#selected_picture').on('click', function(e){
        offset = $('#selected_picture').offset();
        x = e.pageX - offset.left - 25;
        y = e.pageY - offset.top - 25;
        var pin = $('<div class="pin"><img class="pin-img" src="pin.png" /></div>');
        pin.uniqueId();
        $('#pic_wrapper').append(pin);
        pin.css('left', x).css('top', y).show();
```

I need to scale the #selected_picture together with all pins so that they remain at the same relative positions.

I found this example for text in a div: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/VvRoWy

But I can figure out how to apply the approach to my resizable picture with absolutely positioned pins on it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Position the pins with % values instead.

Comment: do you mean the 'e.pageX - offset.left - 25' should be a % of the screen width?

Comment: And the pins are 'position: absolute' - they don't move with resizing

Comment: That's fine, use `%` values for the `top` and `left` positions.

Comment: Also note that you aren't adding the `pin` element to the DOM at any point

Comment: sorry, forgot to copy the pin is actually appended (changed the code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is simple, you calculate the percentage positions of the pin in relation to the image you are clicking. When you use `position: absolute` with percentage `top`/`left` values, it tells the browser to position the element at percentage of **relative parent** width/height, so once the parent dimensions change, your positions will automatically update as well.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#selected_picture').on('click', function(e){
        x = ((e.offsetX) / $(this).width()) * 100 + "%";
        y = ((e.offsetY) / $(this).height()) * 100 + "%";
        var pin = $('<div class="pin"></div>');
        $('#pic_wrapper').append(pin);
        pin.css('left', x).css('top', y).show();
    })
});
```

```css
#pic_wrapper{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
#selected_picture .map {
    display: block;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
.pin {
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pic_wrapper">
    <div id="selected_picture">
        <div class="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That sort of works, but the position changes with scaling. I need the pins to stay at exactly the same position relative to the image. I mean at the same spot of the image

Comment: @linuxoid Changed the code a little bit. Make sure your relative parent (`#pic_wrapper`) will be the same size as image, otherwise the positioning won't be correct.

Comment: They are supposed to move when you resize the image, because they are "attached" by center. So it will look as if they move, but the center will be in the same point. You can actually test it fairly easy - make the pins much smaller (like 5px or so) and you'll see that they are in the same spots.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Thank you very much for your help. They do all now move correctly. But I found that if I click on any, they become detached (the pins are draggable) from the move and always stay at the same spot. And how can I now calculate their new coordinates? What's the event, 'move'?

Comment: @linuxoid Are you sure some other code of yours isn't causing that behaviour? Because in the code i gave the `onclick` handler is not even fired for the `pins` (since they are outside of the `#selected_picture` element)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172254/discussion-between-linuxoid-and-vicbyte).